# How to correctly use Quasar variables in scss style

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, quasar-framework

I have configured a Vue3 + Quasar project via `vue add quasar`. I can't undersand how to use [quasar sass/scss variables](https://quasar.dev/style/color-palette#using-sass-scss-variables).

From the doc I'm expected to use

```
<style lang="scss">
div {
  color: $red-1;
  background-color: $grey-5;
}
</style>
```

but it causes a `Undefined variable.` error due to `$red-1`. If I explicitly import the styling file, I am able to use variables from there, such as `$primary`, but no luck with other Quasar variables.

```
<style lang="scss">
@import './styles/quasar.variables.scss';

div {
  color: $primary;
}
</style>
```

Shall I explicitly import all the variables from Quasar sass/scss too?

My project is configured like:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

import './assets/main.css'
import { Quasar } from 'quasar'
import quasarUserOptions from './quasar-user-options'

const app = createApp(App)
app.use(Quasar, quasarUserOptions)
app.mount('#app')
```

---

Side question: when using [css classes from Quasar](https://quasar.dev/style/color-palette#using-as-css-classes), `bg-primary` and `bg-secondary` use Quasar-defined primary and secondary color instead of my styling choices. Is it the expected behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Sass/SCSS variables are only available with `quasar-cli` managed apps.

https://quasar.dev/style/sass-scss-variables